# Error installing SDL-ttf-0.6.2.1 in Haskell: cannot find -lSDL_ttf

Tags: cabal-install, sdl-ttf

I'm running into the following problem trying to cabal install reactive-banana-sdl:

```
c:/program files/haskell platform/7.10.2-a/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL_ttf
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
linking dist\build\Graphics\UI\SDL\TTF\Version_hsc_make.o failed (exit code 1)
command was: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\7.10.2-a\mingw\bin\gcc.exe dist\build\Graphics\UI\SDL\TTF\Version_hsc_make.o dist\build\Graphics\UI\SDL\TTF\Version_hsc_utils.o -o dist\build\Graphics\UI\SDL\TTF\Version_hsc_make.exe -LC:PFSDL_ttf-2.0.11-win32-x64 -lSDL_ttf -LC:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.10.2\SDL-0.6.5.1-26jmephxohM5v84vz7MqXX -LC:/PF/sdl/lib -lSDL -L/mingw64/lib -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL -mwindows -LC:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\7.10.2-a\lib\base_GDytRqRVSUX7zckgKqJjgw -lwsock32 -luser32 -lshell32 -LC:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\7.10.2-a\lib\integ_2aU3IZNMF9a7mQ0OzsZ0dS -LC:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\7.10.2-a\lib\ghcpr_8TmvWUcS1U1IKHT0levwg3 -LC:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\7.10.2-a\lib/rts -lm -lwsock32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm
C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\7.10.2-a\bin\hsc2hs.exe returned ExitFailure 1
Failed to install SDL-ttf-0.6.2.1
```

What do I do?

Some details: I'm using Windows 7, and doing this in MINGW64. I've installed sdl-ttf through pacman, downloaded SDL_ttf from https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release-1.2.html, and replaced SDL_platform.h (https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/raw-file/e217ed463f25/include/SDL_platform.h) to fix another error (["winapifamily.h: No such file or directory" when compiling SDL in Code::Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22446008/winapifamily-h-no-such-file-or-directory-when-compiling-sdl-in-codeblocks)). I made sure to include extra directories.

```
cabal install -v3 reactive-banana-sdl --extra-include-dirs=C:\PF\SDL_ttf-2.0.11-win32-x64 --extra-lib-dirs=C:\PF\SDL_ttf-2.0.11-win32-x64
```

Comment: The SDL_ttf download link is for SDL 1.2 - are you perhaps linking against SDL 2.0?  That version requires FreeType 2.0 while the latest is built against 2.4.8.  I don't have much Haskell experience but honestly, I'd build SDL from source.  It's quite easy with CMake -- then you know you have all the required libs/deps.

Comment: @GraemeWicksted How do I check what it's linking against/make it link to the correct SDL?

Comment: I may not be the most helpful with Haskell but this wiki page seems to have what you're looking for: https://wiki.haskell.org/SDL  you probably want hsSDL2-ttf not SDL-ttf